# How to prove Brownian motion is Gaussian Process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I'm reading Bernt Oksendal's "Stochastic Differential Equations" and this is one of the  proof that I'm totally lost.

This is from Ch2.2, page 12-13 (sixth edition).

First, Brownian motion is defined as

$$P^x(B_{t_1}\in F_1, \cdots, B_{t_k}\in F_k) := \\ \int\limits_{F_1 \times \cdots \times F_k}p(t_1, x, x_1)\cdots p(t_k-t_{k-1}, x_{k-1}, x_k)dx_1 \ldots dx_k, \tag{2.2.2}$$
where
$$p(t,x,y) := (2\pi t)^{-n/2}\cdot \exp(-\frac{|x-y|^2}{2t})$$

Then, it says, Brownian motion $B_t$ is Gaussian Process,  i.e. for all $0 \leq t1 \leq \cdots \leq t_k$ the random variable
$Z = (B_{t_1}, \ldots, B_{t_k} ) \in \mathbb{R}^{nk}$   has a (multi)normal distribution. This means that there exists a vector $M \in \mathbb{R}^{nk}$ and a non-negative definite matrix $C = [c_{jm}] \in \mathbb{R}^{nk\times nk}$  such that

$$E^x\left[\exp\left(i\sum_{j=1}^{nk}u_jZ_j\right)\right] = \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j,m}u_jc_{jm}u_m+i\sum_j u_j M_j\right) \tag{2.2.3},$$
for all $u = (u_1, \ldots , u_{nk}) \in \mathbb{R}^{nk}$, where $i =\sqrt{-1}$ is the imaginary unit, and $E^x$ denotes expectation with respect to $P^x$.

Moreover, if (2.2.3) holds then $M = E^x[Z]$ is the mean value of $Z$ (2.2.4),
and $c_{jm} = E^x[(Z_j - M_j)(Z_m -M_m)]$ is the covariance matrix of $Z$
(2.2.5).

Then it goes to the proof:

To see that (2.2.3) holds for $Z = (B_{t_1}, \ldots, B_{t_k} ) $ we calculate its left hand
side explicitly by using (2.2.2) (see Appendix A -- something about multi-normal distribution) and obtain (2.2.3) with

$$M=E^x[Z]=(x, x, \cdots, x)\in \mathbb{R}^{nk} \tag{2.2.6}$$

and
$$C=\begin{pmatrix} t_1 I_n & t_1 I_n & \cdots & t_1 I_n \\ t_1 I_n & t_2 I_n & \cdots & t_2 I_n\\ \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\ t_1 I_n & t_2 I_n & \cdots & t_k I_n \end{pmatrix} \tag{2.2.7} $$

Hence
$$E^x[B_t] = x \text{,     for all} t\geq 0 \tag{2.2.8}$$
and
$$E^x[(B_t-x)^2]=nt, E^x[(B_t-x)(B_s-x)]=n \min(s,t) \tag{2.2.9}$$

I'm totally lost on how it just jump to the conclusion of (2.2.6) - (2.2.9).

(2.2.2) seems quite far away from (2.2.3), how could it claim (2.2.3) stands because of (2.2.2) and could give the result for $M$ and $C$?

Also I don't understand how come (2.2.7) looks so weird, the foot note is not normal (i,j) format, I could not figure out how this conclusion was reached....

Comment: Do you understand how to get $(2.2.9)$ from the form of $C$?

Comment: 2.2.7 form is due to the fact that $Cov(B_t,B_s)=min(t,s)$, so on the first row and column (describing $Cov(B_1,B_i)$ and $Cov (B_i,B_1)$)since $t_1<t_i$ for any $i$ then you get $t_1$; now it's made more unreadable by the fact that it is not the cov of 1D Brownian motion , but n-dim Brownian motion, which is why you have the identity matrix in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution to avoid painful computations, using standard results, is the following. For the sake of simplicity, let us consider the 1-dimensional case and $x=0$ (the idea for those cases is the same, but the computations are longer).

1. Define $T(x_1,\ldots,x_k):=\left(\sum_{i=1}^j x_i\right)_{j=1}^k=(x_1,x_1+x_2,\ldots, x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_k)$.
2. Rewrite the p.d.f. of (2.2.2) as:
   $$
   \dfrac{1}{\prod_{j=1}^k \left(2\pi(t_j-t_{j-1})\right)^{1/2}}\text{exp} \left(\sum_{j=1}^k\dfrac{(z_j-z_{j-1})}{2(t_j-t_{j-1})} \right)
   $$
3. Use the change of variables theorem (it is a straightforward formula), noting that $\det{T}=1$, to show that $X:=T^{-1}(Z)$ has a density of the form:
   $$
   \prod_{j=1}^k\rho^\mathcal{N}_{t_j-t_{j-1}}(x_j),
   $$
   where $\rho^\mathcal{N}_{\sigma^2}$ is the p.d.f. of a normal variable with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$.
4. It is standard now, as the density is the one of a Gaussian vector with independent components, that the characteristic function is:
   $$
   E^0\left[\exp\left(i\sum_{j=1}^{k}u_jX_j\right)\right] = \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j,m}u_j\tilde{c}_{jm}u_m\right) \tag{2.2.3'}
   $$
   where
   $$
   \tilde{C}=(\tilde{c}_{ij})_{i,j}=(\delta_{ij}(t_j-t_{j-1}))_{i,j}
   $$
   with $t_0:=0$.
5. To finally obtain the characteristic function of $Z$, we know that it is going to be of the form of (2.2.3) with
   $$
   C=M_T \tilde{C} M_T^t
   $$
   where $M_T$ is the associated matrix of $T$, i.e., $(M_T)_{ij}\equiv M_{ij}=\sum_{l=1}^{i}\delta_{lj}$,
   $$
   M_T= \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0  \\
   1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0  \\
   1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0  \\
   &\ldots  &\ldots &\ldots &\ldots&\ldots \\
   1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1&1
   \end{bmatrix} .
   $$
   Thus,
   $$
   c_{ij}=\sum_{l,m}\left(\sum_{r=1}^{i}\delta_{rl}\delta_{lm}(t_l-t_{l-1})\sum_{s=1}^{j}\delta_{sm}\right)= \sum_{r=1}^{i}\sum_{s=1}^{j}\delta_{rs}(t_r-t_{r-1})=\sum_{r=1}^{m}(t_r-t_{r-1})=t_m 
   $$
   where $m:=\min\{i,j\}$. So we get (2.2.3) and (2.2.7).

Comment: sorry I don't understand the 1st step, could you pls elaborate on what is $T$?

Comment: I have added an additional expression for clarification.

Comment: Is it clear now?